# Spring / Vaadin throws java.io.EOFException on upload file (immediatelly)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I've implemented a file upload with Spring Boot (2.2.7.RELEASE) and Vaadin (14.2.3). However, when I try to upload a file I get a `java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket`. The exception occurs immediatelly after a second or so (maybe about 1 % is upload at this time). Also, the file size doesn't matter. I run into this with large files (15 MB) and small files (< 1 MB).

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2920)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3201)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1171)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterMap(Request.java:1150)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameterMap(RequestFacade.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.parseParameters(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getParameter(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:407)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.HandlerHelper.isRequestType(HandlerHelper.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.ensureCookiesEnabled(VaadinServlet.java:413)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:242)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    ...
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2873)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:362)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:769)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:42)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1114)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:249)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:336)
    ... 116 common frames omitted
```

I already tried some Spring configurations:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: false
      max-file-size: 100MB
      max-request-size: 1000MB
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm currently seeing the same exception with a similar stack trace in my application (Spring Boot v2.3.3.RELEASE, Vaadin 8.11.0). I tends to happen more often with larger files though, there is no clear limit though. Sometimes files ~500KB failm sometimes they succeed. Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: I could fix my issue by setting the ImmediateMode of the Vaadin Upload Component to false. I don't know if such an option exists in Vaadin 14 though.